# How to save and retrieve values of text box of type read only?

Tags: java, html

I want to calculate fee total of student,I getting values of fee and when i give discount,concession to student that values store in database.

when i am saving values of disabled text box,It was not saving in database.

Comment: You can pass values to a hidden textbox before passing to db

Answer (score 0):

don't use disabled if you want to use value after submit. Use `readonly`
i.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="text" readonly>
```

or remove `disable` on submit i.e.:

If you're using jQuery, the equivalent would be:

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
   $('#my-input-id').prop('disabled', false);
   event.preventDefault();
});
```